# How do apps use sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android apps development and I have a basic sqlite question.
What if two different apps use a table with the same name and signature, won't there be any conflicts? Does each app create it's own sqlite instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every application has its own database ([see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)). Applications can share data among each other by using [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Each application (by default, with some exceptions) creates it's own sqlite database in its own folder. Thus, other application cannot have access (by default) to this database. Databases can be shared between applications using ContentProviders.